# How to combine DDD(Domain-driven design) DCI to design a application

Tags: domain-driven-design, dci

DDD is Domain-Driven Design , it is a methodology that include ubiquitous language, root entity , value object and aggregations..

DCI: Data, Context, Interactions is a programming paradigm invented by Trygve Reenskaug.

how can I combine with them in a new system?

Answer (score 5):

This is a subject of on going discussion, and something you'll probably find better answers to at the object-composition Google group where it has been discussed earlier. Also there is an effort to port the canonical DDD sample to DCI at the DCI github page.

Long story overly short though: DCI fits within a Bounded Context, where you'd then have a DCI context per use case.

Comment: thanks, here is a article about it: http://jivejdon.blogspot.com/2011/09/ddd-dci-and-domain-events-example.html

Comment: DCI promotes dumb data. while DDD promotes methods on domain model classes. so???

Comment: @Hendy Irawan: DCI not only promotes dumb data, it also promotes roles that can be assigned to these dumb data objects. These roles implement the domain behavior. So the dumb data /classes/ have next to no behavior but the /objects/ have behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you read through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx I believe the DCI notion of a "context" would be synonymous with a "process manager".  Instead of the process manager calling methods on the aggregates, it would apply roles to the aggregates and coordinate using those.  A "bounded context" could have several "process managers" aka "contexts".  What do you think?